# How do I force Coderush to always display the context menu when I trigger a Refactor?

Tags: refactoring, coderush

It seems that starting v9.3 by default CodeRush disables the Refactor context menu and performs the Refactor if there is only one option. How do I force Coderush to always display the context menu when I trigger a Refactor even if there is only one option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the CodeRush Options screen - **DevExpress\Options** (Or Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O)

Then locate the **Editor\Smart Tags** options page.

On this page, the 2nd radio button has a choice between **"Execute the provider immediately"**  and **"Show the available provider on a menu"**

You should pick the 2nd of these options for the effect you're after and then **press ok**